# Profile's href attribute shows empty string on creation Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, signals

After creating a new user, profile of user is created but it doesn't show default image. When I check view page source, src attribute show empty string like `src=''`. But when I go to profile link where I can update my profile then at that time it automatically load default image and and all the posts created by that user will get that default image.

New user created and new post added by user

[image: New user created and new post added by user]

when I click user profile, it automatically load default image

[image: when I click user profile]

and all posts created by that user get the default image.
[image]

View page source
[image]

`mdoels.py`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

`forms.py`

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

`view.py`

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user.profile, files=request.FILES)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form':u_form,
        'p_form':p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

`signals.py`

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Is it because of signals or line Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user) in profile view ?
before that I had an error: `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist. User has no profile`. I solved using Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user).

**Edit: profile template added**
`profile.html`

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}
  {{ user }}'s' Profile
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="content-section">
    <div class="media">
      <img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" alt="" class="rounded-circle account-img">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="account-heading"> {{ user.username }} </h2>
        <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
        {{ u_form|crispy }}
        {{ p_form|crispy }}
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Dont pass any arguments here -   `super().save(*args, **kwargs)`.. Should be like this.. `super().save()`

Comment: but we need to accept any other arguments that our parent class might be expecting. And I've checked there is no change. I've same problem.

Comment: can you please share your template? it might be a tag problem

Comment: @Pol Frances added profile template

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your django version, so you have to check the one you have. I'm going to develop an example on Django 2.2 because is what I use, but you can adapt just by following what is added on the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#static) for your version.

Basically you need to load the `staticfiles` tag on template and then on the form you'll need to add the `form.media`

So you can try to add on your template the following: (`# this line added`)

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load staticfiles %}  # this line added


{% block title %}
  {{ user }}'s' Profile
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="content-section">
    <div class="media">
      <img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" alt="" class="rounded-circle account-img">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="account-heading"> {{ user.username }} </h2>
        <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.media }}  # this line added
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
        {{ u_form|crispy }}
        {{ p_form|crispy }}
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I had this same problem long time ago and that's what solved it for me. Hope it works for you.

Comment: I'm using 3.0.7 and in my case, it would be static tag but I'm not using a static image. I'm using a dynamic image that is URL will be changing. Also, I tried if-else but no luck. <img src="{% if user.profile.image.url %}{{ user.profile.image.url }} {% else %}{% static 'media/default.png' %}{% endif %}" alt="" class="rounded-circle account-img"> Also if in case I was using static and don't load it it would have raised an error. static not load or something like that.